# How to fetch a matching record from an array in python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've a following array in python. I want to retrieve the record with an id. Is there a way to do it other than checking id field of each record by iterating through all the records. Is there a better way to do it ?

```
[
    {
        'id': 'zy0Wk',
        'name': 'vendor_change_order_status.txt',
        'path': 'templates/messages/vendor_change_order_status.txt'
     },
     {
        'id': 'JTo8c',
        'name': 'vendor_change_order_status_accepted.txt',
        'path': 'templates/messages/vendor_change_order_status_accepted.txt'
     },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
filtered_list = [i for i in my_list if i.get('id') == 'zy0Wk']
```

Although this record is compact, it's also use iteration over your list.

Comment: is there some inbuilt methods to do it without iteration.

Comment: @SaviourTom No. But where this list come from? Do you use Django ORM to get this list? In this case you can use Django `objects.filter()` method. If you need to permorm multiple search on your list check @abarnert answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just doing a single lookup, there's really nothing better than checking record by record.

But if you're going to do a *lot* of lookups on the same data, you want to transform that list into a dict, keyed by the ids:

```
lst = [
    {
        'id': 'zy0Wk',
        'name': 'vendor_change_order_status.txt',
        'path': 'templates/messages/vendor_change_order_status.txt'
     },
     {
        'id': 'JTo8c',
        'name': 'vendor_change_order_status_accepted.txt',
        'path': 'templates/messages/vendor_change_order_status_accepted.txt'
     },
]
dct = {element['id']: element for element in lst}
```

Now, you can look things up a lot more simply:

```
thingy = dct['JTo8c']
```

And it's also a lot more efficient. Looking things up in a list takes linear time—you have to compare it to every element in the list. Looking things up in a hash table (what a dict uses under the covers) takes constant time—you hash it, and you do a single compare, and you know that it's either there, or not there.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. This isn't *quite* true, because different keys can have equal hashes. But if you expand the dictionary whenever you have too many collisions, you end up with amortized constant-time cost, and Python does that for you automatically.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you could modify the object that's being returned, you might be better structuring it as a dictionary of dictionaries like so:

```
my_list = {
    'zy0Wk': {
        'name': 'vendor_change_order_status.txt',
        'path': 'templates/messages/vendor_change_order_status.txt'
    },
    'JTo8c': {
        'name': 'vendor_change_order_status_accepted.txt',
        'path': 'templates/messages/vendor_change_order_status_accepted.txt'
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve the values for an id by doing the following:

```
>>> my_record = my_list['zy0Wk']
>>> print(my_record)
{'path': 'templates/messages/vendor_change_order_status.txt', 'name': 'vendor_change_order_status.txt'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this action only once than the answer is no. But if you need to do this retrieving a lot of times you can construct a dictionary and use `id` as key:

```
a = [
    {
        'id': 'zy0Wk',
        'name': 'vendor_change_order_status.txt',
        'path': 'templates/messages/vendor_change_order_status.txt'
    },
    {
        'id': 'JTo8c',
        'name': 'vendor_change_order_status_accepted.txt',
        'path': 'templates/messages/vendor_change_order_status_accepted.txt'
    },
]

d = {x["id"]:x for x in a}

print(d["zy0Wk"])
print(d["JTo8c"])
```